# Illustrator canvas size unit won't change

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, measurement, units

I'm having this problem with illustrator where, even though I have already changed all units to millimeters (`general`, `stroke` and `type`), the measurements of artboards and canvases are still being measure in points, both in the suggested presets like in the image here

[image]

as well as when making a custom one. What do I have to do to change this to millimeters?

Answer (score 1):

The Presets will always show that way. As you see some show their measurements in Points and some in Pixels.

Simply go to File> New or choose the Create New button from the home screen and you can set your Artboard size in the units of your choice.

[image]

Comment: What version of Illustrator is this?  I'm still on CC 2018 and all print presets are shown in mm, and not points. [see screenshot](https://imgur.com/75LugTH). I wonder if this is region specific thing.

Comment: What's your region @BillyKerr

Comment: @AnFa - I'm in the UK, my Windows PC is set up for UK, and my Illustrator installation was set to "International English"

Comment: @BillyKerr I changed my language to International English and it still is using point units in that screen. This is CC 2022

Comment: @ Billy Kerr- I opened 2018 (I use 2021 these days) and it seems you are correct about the preset units being regional. I set all units to mm and still the presets in the Print section show up in points and pixels. Probably has to do with the initial AI install ? I never see this as I never use the Home screen- I have set in Preferences> General uncheck Show Home Screen when no Documents are open- and checked Use Legacy file "File New" interface. I really do not like the whole home screen thing. And @AnFa, this may be a solution for you so that your Units stay in mm. Just don't use the presets

Comment: @Kyle - yeah, sounds like a complex issue. I tried googling it. There are a few bits and pieces on the Adobe help site, but it's all over the place.  Don't know if Adobe has any documentation on this behaviour, I couldn't find any.

Comment: @AnFa - I have to confess I'm not really sure what is going on here. It may remain a mystery until Adobe explains it (which might never happen).

Comment: @BillyKerr i bet you can edit teh preset file though